# Jupyter Notebook 5.0 - Revert old Table style

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

Is it possible to revert to the old style of the table view as shown in this changelog?

http://blog.jupyter.org/2017/04/04/jupyter-notebook-5-0/

I would really like to use the table style shown in 'Before:' but I don't know what I need to tweak to achieve this.

Thanks!

Comment: I agree. The new table style with the alternating colors is just unreadable.

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though the PR that changed the table style is [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/pull/1776/files), so perhaps copying over the previous css into your `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css` file will do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

After doing an upgrade to Jupyter 5, autocomplete didn't work and everything was super-slow, I also wanted the old table format back. What I did to downgrade to Jupyter 4 was this:

1. Do `pip install package==version` for all of these packages:

   - jupyter (1.0.0)
   - jupyter-client (4.4.0)
   - jupyter-console (5.0.0)
   - jupyter-core (4.2.0)
   - qtconsole (4.2.1)
   - nbconvert (4.2.0)
   - ipywidgets (5.2.2)
   - ipykernel (4.5.0)
   - notebook (4.2.3)

e.g. `pip install qtconsole==4.2.1`

This will revert to an older version that has the previous table format.

2. In order to solve the missing autocomplete feature downgrade `jedi` by:

   - `pip install jedi==0.9.0`

solution found here: https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/10493#issuecomment-298966390

This worked for me, but I am sure there are many different combinations of these packages and versions that will do the trick.